# Switching framebuffers while rendering and waiting for the result

Tags: opengl

I've the problem that i want to switch framebuffers while rendering and use the framebuffer immediately when i switching back. Actually this results in a empty framebuffer which is not the expected result as you can imagine.

As i already used framebuffers before i found out that it's working if the framebuffer i want to display is rendered before the i start rendering the framebuffer to which the other one is rendered to.

#### Not working renderpath

- Render to FBO0
- Start rendering to FBO1
- Switch back to FBO0
- Render FBO1 into FB0

#### Working path

- Render into FBO1
- Render into FBO0
- Render FBO1 into FBO0

As it looks like a sync issue i want to know how to prevent this? Is there any command that ensures that the rendering to the previous renderbuffer has been completed? While it's currently working its not what i call a safe solution because i think there could be the same issue later if the content to render into FBO1 is getting much bigger.

#### Code

Here is the code which starts the rendering:

```
GLFramebuffer.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.FRAMEBUFFER, _FramebufferHandle);
#if DEBUG
FramebufferStatus status = GLFramebuffer.CheckFramebufferStatus(FramebufferTarget.FRAMEBUFFER);
if (status != FramebufferStatus.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
{
    GLFramebuffer.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferHandle.Default);
    throw new OpenGLException(GLFramebuffer.GetStatusString(status));
}
#endif
RenderStack.Push(Tuple.Create(this, attachments));
GL.Viewport(0, 0, Width, Height);
```

And the code which stops the rendering:

```
Tuple<Framebuffer, FramebufferAttachement[]> peeked;
if (RenderStack.Count == 0 || (peeked = RenderStack.Peek()).Item1 != this)
{
    if (RenderStack.Any(p => p.Item1 == this))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Framebuffer is not the top framebuffer, you must call 'StopRendering()' on all previous used buffers");
    }
    else throw new InvalidOperationException("Framebuffer is not in the rendering stack, please use 'StartRendering(...)' to use the current framebuffer");
}
AssertDisposed();

RenderStack.Pop();
if (RenderStack.Count == 0)
{
    GLFramebuffer.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferHandle.Default);
}
else
{
    Rebind(peeked);
}
```

And the rebind method:

```
GLFramebuffer.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.FRAMEBUFFER, peeked.Item1._FramebufferHandle);
var attachments = peeked.Item2;
if (attachments.Length > 1)
{
    GLFramebuffer.DrawBuffers(attachments.Select(p => (DrawBuffersEnum)p).ToArray());
}
GL.Viewport(0, 0, peeked.Item1.Width, peeked.Item1.Height);
```

The methods are just wrapped, so `GLFramebuffer.DrawBuffers` is equal to `glDrawBuffers`.

Comment: The OpenGL Wiki on "memory model" suggests that you use `glMemoryBarrier` to _"establish visibility between one rendering command and some later OpenGL operation"_, but I daresay that this is bollocks. Render-to-texture using FBOs has worked just fine decades before anyone thought of any such thing as `glMemoryBarrier`. Are you sure you're not invoking UB by having the render-to texture accidentially bound to both FBOs, and sure you're not using a wrong target, or something? Normally, this **must** work just fine, and OpenGL automatically syncs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

> **Not working renderpath**
>
> - Render to FBO0
> - Start rendering to FBO1
> - Switch back to FBO0
> - Render FBO1 into FBO0

should actally work, as issuing commands rendering FBO1 content to FBO0 creates a so called *implicit synchronization point* on operations happening to FBO0 and FBO1 to complete before their data is combined in further steps.

Either the OpenGL implementation you use has a bug, or you're doing something wrong. We need to see some code.

Comment: @FelixK. You missed to include the `RenderStack::Push` method. But my gut says me, that somewhere between your pushing and poping framebuffers into a custom render stack, something isn't unwound correctly, or you leave some attachment dangling around.

Comment: Well the pushing and popping is just using the `Stack<T>`of .NET. The code which binds framebuffers is shown above. What do you mean with: "Leave some attachment dangling around"?

Comment: @FelixK.: For example if you have a texture bound to a FBO as color attachment and use it at the same time as a sampling source (i.e. bound to an active texture unit which is used as a texture sampler in the fragment shader). With renderbuffers it's harder to mess this up, but you can get in unpleasant situations as well.

Comment: Well it turned out that i had a bug, funny that nobody noticed it: `Rebind(peeked)` refered actually to the current draw framebuffer but should be the the next framebuffer in the stack. Noticed this when i implemented a new render manager.